# How do I import self-created modlues in Python | I keep getting a module not found error

Tags: python, module, importerror

[image: 1]

Keep getting a module error here, though I created the module

Comment: To help better answer a question, you need to provide code/config snippets you tried, errors you got, and docs you looked up. Please consider improving your question. The question ideally should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Comment: Is the module in the same directory as your python file

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named literally `__init__.py` in the same directory; see duplicate [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Answer (score 0):

Add these codes to the `ping.py` file before you import the `moving_ping`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\ssand\OneDrive\Desktop")
```

If it does not work remember to add an empty `__init__.py` file under the `C:\Users\ssand\OneDrive\Desktop\PingPong` folder.

Comment: @slimsydcodes does it work or not?